Предложение с однородными придаточными
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая перед «и»?
«Это блюдо создано для настоящих ценителей — тех, кто много что пробовал и кому всегда мало».

§ 109. Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными


Между однородными придаточными предложениями, соединенными неповторяющимся соединительным или разделительным союзом, запятая не ставится, например: Чудилось, будто корчуют сразу весь лес и выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли (Федин) (повторяющихся союзов здесь нет: первый союз и соединяет два придаточных предложения, второй – два однородных подлежащих корни и земля, третий – два однородных сказуемых стонут и вопят); Что это за соединение и кто такой Ковпак, мы тогда ещё не знали (Медведев).


• Так что не нужна в этом предложении запятая перед союзом "и".
Правильно использовать не "много что", а "много чего" (много — кого? чего?).
Это блюдо создано для настоящих ценителей — тех, кто много чего пробовал и кому всегда мало.
• Пример
Теперь не надо ломать голову, что делать с типами вроде того же Трифона, то есть с теми, кто много чего знает и кого отпускать так просто нельзя (А. Васильев. Место под солнцем).

Не очень понятна грамматика предложения, а именно ТЕХ, КТО...и КОМУ. Какое здесь средство связи  и тип придаточного.  Местоимение ТЕХ не повторяется, но иногда может повторяться. Есть особые правила для таких конструкций?

Если местоимение "тех" повторяется. то действуют обычные правила для обособления придаточных, то есть добавляются две запятые: тех, кто много чего пробовал, и тех, кому всегда мало. В примере местоимение тоже не повторяется.

Не напомните мне правило, где указано про повтор местоименной части.  Не получилось найти, а помню, что где-то было. Кстати, здесь даже не союз, а союзное слово (связь местоименная, союзов нет).  Немного необычное сочетание.  Указательное слово всегда относится к главному предложению, а союзное слово к придаточному.

Кстати, некоторые авторы запятую после местоимения почему-то не ставят https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/для+тех+кто Был бы кто один, а то их много.  Может, устойчивость какую видят. Тоже информация для размышления, отсюда и мой интерес к правилу.

Правильно:
Это блюдо создано для настоящих ценителей (каких именно?) — тех, кто много что пробовал и кому всегда мало.
Пояснение

Предложение имеет присоединительный речевой оборот, включающий однородные придаточные. Придаточные местоименно-определительные, связь местоименная, союзов нет: тех — кто, тех — кому.

Придаточные связаны союзом И, но при этом имеют общее указательное слово ТЕХ. Специального правила для местоименной связи не нашлось, поэтому используем тему сложных подчинительных союзов с местоименной частью, когда в предложении есть параллельные конструкции (пункт 3):
4) включение первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд 
однородных членов предложения или параллельных 
конструкций. 
Река приняла особенный вид потому, что вода видна сквозь 
голые сучья, а еще более потому, что пропал от холода 
водяной цвет (Акс.); Хозяйственная часть в доме 
Пшеницыной процветала не потому только, что Агафья 
Матвеевна была образцовая хозяйка, но и потому ещё, что 
Иван Матвеевич Мухояров был в гастрономическом отношении 
великий эпикуреец (Гонч.); Нехлюдов заехал к тётушкам 
потому, что имение их было по дороге к прошедшему вперёд 
его полку, и потому, что они его очень об этом просили 
(Л. Т.); Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слёз от своего 
бессилия и растерянности, и от боли за оскорблённую 
Шурочку, и оттого, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки 
кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова (Купр.).


Рассмотрим пример с повтором местоименного слова.  В этом случае союз И соединяет местоименные части, а союзные части обособляются: Это блюдо создано для настоящих ценителей — тех, кто много что пробовал,  и тех, кому всегда мало.

Но если местоименная часть является общей, то запятая при наличии союза И между союзными частями не ставится.


Примечание.
Почему иногда не ставят запятую в сочетании для тех кто, в Карте слов много таких примеров. Я полагаю, что пользователи считают, что это сложный союз, который они могут не расчленять по образцу союза для того чтобы. Но это не сложный союз, а местоименное указательное слово, поэтому запятая должна стоять.
